# How to convert from TSV file to JSON file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

So I know this question might be duplicated but I just want to know and understand how can you convert from TSV file to JSON? I've tried searching everywhere and I can't find a clue or understand the code.

So this is not the Python code, but it's the TSV file that I want to convert to JSON:

```py
title   content difficulty
week01  python syntax   very easy
week02  python data manipulation    easy
week03  python files and requests   intermediate
week04  python class and advanced concepts  hard
```

And this is the JSON file that I want as an output.

```py
[{
        "title": "week 01",
        "content": "python syntax",
    "difficulty": "very easy"
    },
    {
        "title": "week 02",
        "content": "python data manipulation",
    "difficulty": "easy"
    },
    {
        "title": "week 03",
        "content": "python files and requests",
    "difficulty": "intermediate"
    },
    {
        "title": "week 04",
        "content": "python class and advanced concepts",
    "difficulty": "hard"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in modules you need for this are [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

To read tab-separated data with the CSV module, use the `delimiter="\t"` parameter:

Even more conveniently, the CSV module has a DictReader that automatically reads the first row as column keys, and returns the remaining rows as dictionaries:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
    data = list(reader)
    return json.dumps(data)
```

The JSON module can also write directly to a file instead of a string.

Comment: This works, thanks. But to get the output I wanted, I just need to put "indent = 4" as argument in the json.dumps function

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `pandas` you can use the [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method with the option `orient="records"`to obtain the list of entries you want.

```py
my_data_frame.to_json(orient="records")
```